# What privileges are required to create a user in Oracle with a non DBA user?

Tags: sql, oracle

What should be the privileges existing on an Oracle User to create a user?
I'm trying to execute the following command from a Java program and hit the following exception multiple times:

**Oralce 12.1 Command:**

```
CREATE USER USERTABLE IDENTIFIED BY USERPASSWORD 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE MYTABLESPACE 
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON MYTABLESPACE
```

**Stacktrace:**

> Error :java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>
> Error occurred while processing the request. Error from database server or driver.java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

The following privileges are assigned to the user:

```
GRANT ALTER ANY INDEX TO dummyuser;
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO dummyuser; 
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO dummyuser; 
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO dummyuser; 
GRANT DROP ANY TABLE TO dummyuser; 
GRANT GLOBAL QUERY REWRITE TO dummyuser; 
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO dummyuser; 
GRANT UNDER ANY TABLE TO dummyuser; 
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO dummyuser WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Can someone please let me know if there are any other privileges that needs to be assigned to this user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the forthcoming issues that I had got, after @Marmite Bomber's answer - I had applied the following change to the user for my JUnits!

```
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO cordysdemo;
commit;
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Happy testing with **DBA privileges**;) Note that you should follow the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/doc.121/e36415/sec_over_princ.htm#EMSEC12762)

Answer (score 1):

Chect the [`CREATE USER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm) priviledge.

But you typically do not create database users using your JDBC client. This is more a static task done by the `DBA`s.

Comment: Yeah, this is been run under a suite of regression tests.